# What is the RegEx pattern for 24-06-2015 10:15:45: Aditya Krishnakant:?

Tags: python, regex, typeerror

What is the RegEx pattern for `24-06-2015 10:15:45: Aditya Krishnakant:`

If you look at the whatsapp chat transcript, it looks like a mess. The purpose of this code is to print messages sent by a person in a new line (for better readability). This is my code

```
import re

f = open("wa_chat.txt", "r")
match = re.findall(r'(\d{2})\:(\d{2})\:(\d{4})\s(\d{2})\:(\d{2})\:(\d{2})\:\s(\w)\s(\w)\:', f)
for content in match:
      print(f.readlines(), '\n')
f.close()
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "whatsapp.py", line 4, in <module>
   match = re.findall(r'(\d{2})\:(\d{2})\:(\d{4})\s(\d{2})\:(\d{2})\:(\d{2})\:\s(\w)\s(\w)\:', f)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 177, in findall
   return_compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Could you give the full traceback? Which line causes the issue? Why have you placed that code in the body of a class definition? What debugging have you done?

Comment: Try to apply the regex to `f.read()`

Comment: In the code there's an extra "r" re.findall(r <-- is this important?

Comment: @Daemedeor that's not relevant to this question, it means *"`r`aw string"* and helps avoid [the backslash plague](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#the-backslash-plague)

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have updated the question :) . I am actually learning python. I thought that the code will become reusable if it is inside a class (inheritance).

Comment: @cricket_007 f.read() gave the same error

Comment: I would recommend you have a look at http://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F and pick a structured tutorial to work through. Inheritance and reusability, although related in some cases, are not the same thing.

Comment: I would suggest `strprime` over regex since you are dealing with a DateTime format

Answer (score 1):

For some reason you're putting `\:` where `-` should be. Also, instead of `\s` you can be more specific and just use a space. You can be more specific with those kinds of things because you know exactly what the format is. Your other big problem is that you're only using `\w`, which only matches one alphanumeric character, when you should use `\w+`, matching the whole word. Lastly, your actual error is coming from the fact that you're passing in a file object instead of the string containing its contents, i.e. `f.read()`. Here's some code that should work:

```
import re

f = open("wa_chat.txt", 'r')
match = re.findall(r'(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}): (\w+) (\w+):', f.read())
print match #or do whatever you want with it
```

Note that `match` will be a list of tuples since you wanted to use grouping.